# Is it possible to run command "route -n" specifically for a NIC

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am fairly new to linux I wanted to ask if its possible in linux commands to run a "route -n" command to retrieve information for a specific NIC. E.G route -n ether0. Because currently it shows me for all the NIC's but what if I want just for one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want see route for ether0, you can use below command

```
ip -o route show dev ether0
```

or

```
ip route show | grep ether0
```

or

```
route -n | grep ether0
```

or

```
netstat -nr | grep ether0
```

To see NIC for ether0, you can use ifconfig command and Gateway NIC you can use arp -a commands

```
ifconfig ether0
```

for see GW and direct connected NICS you can use below command

```
arp -a
```

Comment: As I said in my answer yesterday, using `grep ether0` rather than a filter directly on the `ip route` command provides incomplete results -- it shows only routes that *directly* attach to the NIC, but not routes that do so indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the iproute2 `ip` command (rather than the antique `route` command), and provide a selector with your NIC:

```
# for ether0
ip -o route list dev ether0
```

(I've added `-o` since your tags indicate that you're using this for scripting purposes; ensuring that each result lives on its own line is appropriate in this case).

This is a significant improvement on the simple `route | grep ether0` approach, as it shows routing entries which can end up sending traffic through a NIC but don't name that NIC explicitly.

As the default for iproute2 is to avoid leaning on the resolver, no local flag equivalent to `-n` is necessary; instead, if you *did* want to use the resolver, you would need to add `-r`.